# URL Rewrite for SSL

Tags: apache, https, url-rewriting

I have SSL configured for a `cart` directory in my website. I'm having a very difficult time trying to configure SSL for a different directory within the same website. I ask the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806631/ssl-on-multiple-directories) on SO, and was hoping it would eventually get migrated here for more help (I don't want to make the same post twice).

Anyway, after awhile I noticed the directory I need SSL on, `/admin`, is actually accepting both `http` and `https`, so now to make my life easier and get this out of the way.. I'm just trying to configure a URL Rewrite for

`http://www.shop.com/admin/index.php`

to rewrite to

`https://www.shop.com/admin/index.php`

This is what I have tried, and it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^https://www.shop.com/admin/index.php$ http://www.shop.com/admin/index.php
```

How can rewrite the default page for this directory to use https? I know this is probably sloppy, but I don't know what else to do. If you could help me set up ssl legitly for this directory, that would be even better.

ps - The url rewrite [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) are complicated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.shop.com/admin/$1 [R,L]
```

You may need to replace the `$1` with just `index.php` instead.

Comment: Sweet!! It worked, thank you so much. Would mind telling me what `[R,L]` does?

Comment: Yes sure: the `R` means "redirect" where you could specify `R=301` (assumed) or `R=302` which has to be done manually. The `L` if I remember correctly, is for "Symbolic Link" but I could be wrong. I just know they work, so don't remove them.